# Testing Facebook App Ads for Installs

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, ads

I am following this guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads and I've done everything as explained: added the Facebook SDK, triggered the "app activate" event with the corresponding App ID in the app delegate, set up the Info.plist with the ID. When I test my application through the simulator and on a testing device I open App Dashboard -> Insights -> App Events -> Overview and I get track of "fb_mobile_activate_app" events almost instantly, they are incrementing. Is this all I should have to know the SDK is implemented correctly and I can update my app on the App Store without worries and then run an Ads campaign on Facebook? 
I am asking also because the things are a bit confusing on the Insights -> "Mobile App Installs" page:

> This dashboard shows organic and paid app installs reported by either the Facebook SDK for iOS, the Facebook SDK for Android, or a Mobile Measurement Partner. This dashboard serves as as an indicator of app install volume, user demographics, and as a baseline for understanding how ads are increasing installs of your app. Developers can also use this dashboard for debugging to ensure that app installs are being recorded. For detailed data on paid installs, see the analytics in the Ads Manager.
>   Users who are not logged into a version of the Facebook mobile app released since August 2012 are not counted here.

How do you guys understand this line *Developers can also use this dashboard for debugging to ensure that app installs are being recorded.*? How can you debug this without having an ad and why do I get zeros on the "Mobile App Installs" graph? Is it possible that Facebook have a faulty description or am I understanding it wrong? Thanks

Comment: Did you get the answer for this ?

Comment: I can only say that everything I described here about the setup was enough for the tracking to be working. I am surprised that almost 2 years after posting this Facebook don't have a good way for testing their SDK integration.

Comment: stupid facebook